# iPhone - ASIHTTP and showing progress for long downloads

Tags: iphone, download

Im planning on using ASIHTTP to handle some long file downloads/installs and I'd like to give the user a list of downloads in progress which would also allow me to display a broken download so the user can reinitiate the request...

So my plan is to initiate the requests from the AppDelegate, but if the user goes to the download items view I need to then create progress views for each download in progress and somehow hook up the ASIHTTP connection to them.  Can I create the progress views as soon as the download request is made and save them in an array in the app delegate so that the DownloadItemsViewController can then use those progress views when it creates the cells for the tableview? Is there a better way? I have a feeling I'm approaching this wrong.

How would you keep track of the downloads in the AppDelegate? What if the user closes the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much point in having `UIProgressView` (I assume that's what you mean by "the progress views") instances around if you're not displaying them to the user.

You're better off keeping track of the progress for each request (by means of the `request:didReceiveBytes:` progress delegate method) in some sort of download -> progress mapping. For example, you could retain an `NSDictionary` instance with the download `NSURL` instances as keys and `NSNumber` instances representing their progress as a fraction in the range [0.0, 1.0].

Then whenever you wish to alert the user to the progress of their downloads, you can construct `UIProgressView` objects and populate them with the values stored in your `NSDictionary` mapping.

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was being stupid. I keep an array of dictionaries in the AppDelegate and the download progress view is a delegate that receives a [0.0,1.0] range update on the progress for each item downloading.